# jsxgraph: how to change line properties after draw

Tags: javascript

I have

```
obj=board.create('segment'...
```

and I want to do elsewhere:

```
obj.strokeWidth=function() {return 5;} //doesn't work
board.update();
```

or

```
obj.strokeWidth=5;
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to change properties is:

```
obj=board.create('segment'...
obj.setProperty({strokeWidth:5});
```

More than one property can be set by

```
obj.setProperty({strokeWidth:5, strokeColor:'green'});
```